# CSS: Assign ALL images to a specific div with one rule

Tags: css, html, selector, assign, rule

I would like to know whether this is possible at all, and if so, how do I write the css-code?

The background is, I have made an HTML/CSS-site where I have specified a div id with some values, and then, both the image and the caption goes inside this div. Now I would like to make this a bit easier for the people who will manage this site so that they don't have to write any HTML at all; I would like them to be able to just add an image, and then, by this "magic" rule, the image will be put into this specific div, together with the caption. But is it possible? I don't know if it's of any relevance, but I have been converting the HTML/CSS-site into a wordpress site, so in the end I will have to translate the selectors into selectors that WP understands (such as caption into wp-caption, and so on). But for now I just want to know if it's possible to assign every image to a certain div in a css-rule?

I would like to write something like:

```
img div {
div-property1;
div-property2;
}
```

in the css-file, so that whenever I add an image and a caption it will automatically use this div.

Comment: But what do you mean by "use" or "assign"?

Comment: Neither HTML or CSS can do 'magic'

Comment: If I understand the question then the answer is 'no', but you can give every image within a particular element a specific style. EG: `.pics img {border:1px solid red;}` will give a red border to every image within an element with a class of 'pics'

Comment: [Agreed - @Moob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977490/css-assign-all-images-to-a-specific-div-with-one-rule/19977524#19977524)

Comment: If you want to wrap an `img` tag with a `div` tag, you need to manimupalte the DOM with JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class selector.

**For Instance,**

```
.yourDivName img{/*your values*/}
```

**The Code:**

```
<div class="yourDivName">
   <img src="" />
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This isn't how i'm interpreting the question. I think the OP wants to 'magically' wrap the img in a div. Maybe... Its not clear.

Comment: Thats the mis-interpretation which we have to clear. - @Moob, as the OP might not have the right knowlegdge, so lets clear his conceptions about it.

Comment: Yes, Moob is right. the problem is that the people who will manage this site don't know any code at all. I mean nada, zip, not the simplest HTML tag. So I don't want them having to code at all (In WP the addition of images is supersimple, they click a button, select an image, and click another button to confirm). When an image is added in WP, certain classes are assigned to it, and this is where I would like to put my "magic transfer-the-image-to-TheDiv" code. I hope this made things a bit clearer. If not, I'll just paste the actual code in here (simplified though).

Comment: Hi Nathan,
I actually don't see your answer anymore. (??) 
Also, I have follow-up questions but maybe I should post them on wordpress support forum instead.

Comment: I believed my answer served up your purpose as you had mentioned, so I removed the comment. If it served your purpose, you can accept them and mention your methodology used, so that I can add it up in my answer. - @Kei

Comment: But if it's gone, how can I accept it?

Actually, I decided not to use it, because it only did "half" of the job.

Comment: show the link of how you used it and add your methodology to know the real issue. - @Kei

Answer (score 0):

So, to clear some things. I got the answer from @Nathan Lee to download a wordpress plugin called Preserved HTML Editor Markup, and some guidance on how to use it. I did so, and it did quite well, and it could very well be the solution for others, but it didn't quite do what I wanted (it stuffed all the images entered through the visual editor into the same `<figure> </figure>`so they weren't styled the way I wanted.. I wanted them to share the same div but then (of course) I wanted each image go into it's own 
`<figure> img src....<figcaption> the caption </figcaption> </figure>`. 
If I knew how I would try to tweak the plugin but I have no idea on where to begin.

I would have liked to accept Nathan's answer, but since he deleted this comment I have no way of doing so. Until further notice on how to go about this I answer my own question like this and hope that everyone will be happy.

Kind regards,
Kei